# How to name an app store icon?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Icon.png - 57x57 pixels application icon for standard resolution iPhone.

Icon@2x.png - 114x114 pixels application icon for high resolution iPhone 4

Icon-Small.png - 29x29 pixels settings icon for standard resolution iPhone.

Icon-Small@2x.png - 58x58 pixels settings icon for high resolution iPhone.

**These are ok. But how to name an app store icon of size 512x512?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has add a new sample code for icons: [Icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Icons/Introduction/Intro.html)
It could help you

Comment: is that a joke? that doesn't have any code in it does it? (regarding icons)

Comment: No, its true... It is just a project with all icons needed for iPhone/iPad/retina support. I think it is a good idea (and should be in default project !)

Comment: oh I see, fair enough - if you download it I guess.

Comment: yeah, agree. They should put default/standard images and icons in the template projects. Always be a Default.png, Icon.png, Icon@2x.png and etc. :) Its difficult to understand, and took me ages to figure out how to do it.

Comment: now it became clear , no need to add application store icon in the code. we have to give application store icon along with build when we submit it in app store.

Answer (score 3):

> iTunesArtwork.png
>
> size 512*512px

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter - and in fact it doesn't matter about the other icons. You can name them whatever you want as long as its the same name in the info.plist file.

Comment: Except if you want to be compatible with older iPhone versions, in which case at least some of the names in the question are required.